# Determine field type by it's name in Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have an interface which takes events in it's API. 
A base event looks like this:

```
class Event<T extends Details> {
    T details;
}
```

An example implementation looks like the following:

```
class UpdateEvent extends Event<UpdateDetails> {

    @JsonProperty("updateDetails")
    UpdateDetails details;

}
```

In the JSON, I would like to serialise/deserialise something like:

```
{
    "updateDetails": {...}
}
```

So, I would need to determine the type of the details field by it's name in Json, and instantiate the according child of the Event class when deserialising.

I have achieved so with creating a custom deserialiser, which checks for the exact name of the details object, but I don't like this solution (serialisation works out of the box because of the JsonProperty annotation). Does Jackson have a solution for this? I couldn't achieve it with the standard JsonTypeInfo annotations (it would always nest the details object one level lower in the JSON, or it would add a new attribute, which I unfortunately cannot do).

Comment: Custom type info.

Comment: Can you take me to an example or something? Couldnt achieve exactly this behaviour.